# How to build JSON from two datatable - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have two datatables. The first datatable structure is:

```
ID    SHORT_NAME                  CARRIER_NAME

1       A                         Carrier A

2       B                         Carrier B

3       C                         Carrier C

4       D                         Carrier D

5       E                         Carrier E

6       F                         Carrier F

7       G                         Carrier G
```

And the another datatable structure is:

```
YMDH                          ID        SELL_DURATION

2009-03-07 00:00:00.000        1        222.999995

2009-03-07 01:00:00.000        1        75.816664

2009-03-07 02:00:00.000        1        39.349995

2009-03-07 03:00:00.000        1        275.91666

2009-03-07 04:00:00.000        1        352.666641

2009-03-07 00:00:00.000        2        80.783324

2009-03-07 01:00:00.000        2        162.049985

2009-03-07 02:00:00.000        2        107.199989

2009-03-07 03:00:00.000        2        44.849994

2009-03-07 04:00:00.000        2        156.516658

2009-03-07 05:00:00.000        2        467.583312

2009-03-07 06:00:00.000        2        455.199977
```

**Update**

This is my code in **Model** class:

```
public class GridModel
{      
    public double ID { get; set; }
    public string SHORT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CARRIER_NAME { get; set; }
    public List<GridSparklineModel> GridSparklineModel { get; set; }
}   

public class GridSparklineModel
{
    public DateTime YMDH { get; set; }
    public double SELL_DURATION { get; set; }
    public string DateString { get { return YMDH.ToString("h tt"); } }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public class GridController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult FetchDataJSON()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        DataSet ds = grid.GetData();      // This gets both datatable

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];      // Here is the first datatable    

        List<GridModel> lst = new List<GridModel>();

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                GridModel model = new GridModel();
                model.ID = Convert.ToDouble(row["ID"].ToString());
                model.SHORT_NAME = row["SHORT_NAME"].ToString();
                model.CARRIER_NAME = row["CARRIER_NAME"].ToString();
                model.GridSparklineModel = new List<GridSparklineModel>();
                double carrierId = Convert.ToDouble(row["ID"].ToString());
                foreach (DataRow item2 in ds.Tables[1].Select("ID =" + carrierId))
                {
                    model.GridSparklineModel.Add(new GridSparklineModel { YMDH = DateTime.Parse(item2["YMDH"].ToString()), SELL_DURATION = Convert.ToDouble(item2["SELL_DURATION"]) });
                }

                lst.Add(model);
            }
        }

        return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I want to build a JSON like this:

```
var nwCustomersWithOrders = 
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "SHORT_NAME": "A",
        "CARRIER_NAME": "Carrier A",
        "SellDuration": [
            {
                "YMDH": "2009-03-07 00:00:00.000",
                "SELL_DURATION": 222.999995
            },
            {
                "YMDH": "2009-03-07 01:00:00.000",
                "SELL_DURATION": 75.816664
            },
            {
                "YMDH": "2009-03-07 02:00:00.000",
                "SELL_DURATION": 39.349995
            },
            {
                "YMDH": "2009-03-07 03:00:00.000",
                "SELL_DURATION": 75.816664
            },
            {
                "YMDH": "2009-03-07 04:00:00.000",
                "SELL_DURATION": 39.349995
            },
            {
                "YMDH": "2009-03-07 05:00:00.000",
                "SELL_DURATION": 275.91666
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Is this the correct way to do? Please help and suggest how can i check if it gives me the correct result or not.

Answer (score 0):

Model your "JsonResult" like this

```
 public JsonResult GetAppointments(double start, double end)
    {
        var apptListForDate = CalendarUtility.LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange(start, end);
        var eventList = from e in apptListForDate
                        select new
                        {
                            id = e.ID,
                            studentid = e.StudentId,
                            student = e.Student,
                            title = e.Title,
                            start = e.StartDateString,
                            end = e.EndDateString,
                            instructor  =e.Instructor,
                            notes = e.Notes,
                            color = e.StatusColor,
                            className = e.ClassName,
                            someKey = e.SomeImportantKeyId,
                            allDay = false
                        };
        var rows = eventList.ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Use the "JsonResult" in a calendar like this...

[image]

Comment: Sorry foxtrotZulu but this is not clear to me. Not sure what apptListForDate  is?

Comment: Oh.. I have a html code like this: var url = '@Url.Action("FetchDataJSON", "Grid")';

            var rawData = null;
            $.ajax({
                // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
                // will return before the data is fetched
                async: false,
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    rawData = data;
                }
            });

Comment: Yea, pay no attention to my code other than the method signature (i.e  public JsonResult) and the return. Try taking your result out of the action and put it in a JsonResult, see if this gets you the correct Json format

Comment: Can i recommend entity framework connection to SQL tables and then use LINQ queries instead of using datatables?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49669/discussion-between-foxtrotzulu-and-user1254053)